# Word for inlets of a mountain

Tags: single-word-requests, geography, image-identification

Can the word `inlet` be used for mountains, too? I'm looking for a word that describes valleys that reach into the mountain, but don't go across it.

Here is a picture that tries to describe what I'm looking for.

[image: Diagram of geography]

I found [this](http://webpages.charter.net/jszecsody2b/geocache/Fr.coulee.air.jpg) picture with a *coulee*. Is that a good word?

I'm not specifically looking for steep valleys or canyons, but rather for soft valleys.

**EDIT**: Thanks a lot for the input. I think I'm going with “a valley that reaches into the mountain but doesn't cross it”. <s>I think `notch` is also good, but isn't as easy to understand for non-native speakers, which are my targeted readers.</s>  Seems like *notch* isn't what I want either. Maybe `combe`?

Comment: It probably depends partly on the specific geological processes that created the feature, but I imagine they'd usually be formed by water erosion. In which case they'd be [ravines](http://www.spellinger.com/ravine) (the example usage in that definition being *"The river washed a ravine into the mountainside"*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Is *ravine* dependent on size? Could a *ravine* be several kilometers wide?

Comment: If the [eroding] water was *frozen*, it would be a *[glacial] [cirque*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cirque_glacier), but I'm not a geologist.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks, but I don't think that's the word I'm looking for. I'm not a geologist either and I don't need a technical term, better would be a word that also non-geologist would understand.

Comment: Coulee are typically made from lava flows. Is your picture of a volcano?

Comment: @Ruut: In my case it could be, because it's a mountain on an island, however I'm more looking for a general term, so maybe `notch` is the correct word.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](http://merriam-webster.com/dictionary/notch) defines notch as "a narrow passage between mountains", which isn't quite what you want. Confirmed by the OED, which adds *chiefly N. Amer.*

Comment: There are probably at least a dozen different terms, some depending on where in the world you are located (ie, what culture and language), and others on how technical/"official" you are trying to be.  In parts of the US it would be a "hollow".

Comment: I would call such formations glacier troughs.

Comment: As you have seen, there are many technical terms depending on the geological process. I don't think these words will  help for non-native speakers much (or even many natives).  What strikes me as awkward about your description is the *directionality* of your valleys, you describe them going into the mountain centres, when all valley forming processes go in the other direction. Perhaps consider 'valleys which radiate from the mountain' or 'valleys which flow from the mountain'. You don't need to specify that they don't cross it because there *is* a different word for those, they are 'passes'.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suggest **valley** or, more specifically, U-shaped valley which, I presume means open-ended.

[image]
http://www.sciencepartners.info/?page_id=1253

[ravine](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ravine) a small, deep, narrow valley

[cirque](http://www.ge-at.iastate.edu/glossary-of-geologic-terms/) A steep-walled hollow in a mountain side, shaped
like an amphitheater, or bowl, with one side partially cut away. Place
of origin of a mountain glacier.

[gully](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=gulley%20definition) a ravine formed by the action of water.

[couloir](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/couloir) a steep gorge or gully on the side of a mountain, especially in the Alps.

**Update**

I have found a diagram that I think covers the subject pretty adequately.

[image]

[Picture from compassdude.com](http://www.compassdude.com/topographic-maps.php)

Comment: When I think of a `valley`, I think of something that crosses *through* the mountain, but maybe I'm just thinking wrong :)

Comment: I'll add some evidence to support the use of 'valley'. Be right back.

Comment: A U-shaped valley is U-shaped in cross-section. It has nothing to do with its being open-ended. (Contrast a V-shaped valley.)

Comment: @TRiG - Have you got a reference for that? Aren't both U- and V-shaped valleys open-ended?

Comment: Where I grew up in California, there were lots of these. We called them *valleys*, whether they went through the hills or not.

Comment: @PeterShor - so you agree with my answer, right?

Comment: Geography class in school. V-shaped valleys are carved by water; U-shaped by ice. So the name has to do with the shape in cross-section. (Both will be open-ended, yes, but that's not where the name comes from, and "open-ended valley" != "U-shaped valley".)

Comment: @chasly: I already up voted it.

Comment: A U-shaped valley has a U-shaped cross-section and was carved by a glacier.  A V-shaped valley has a V-shaped cross-section and was carved by a river.  Neither name is related to the end-to-end shape of the valley.

Comment: Why post a presumption as an answer? Kind of amazed that anyone in the UK comes out of school not knowing what a U shaped valley is... it seemed in my schooldays that we spoke of little but drumlins, terminal moraines, U shaped valleys and roche moutonnées... :)

Answer (score 13):

**draw**  (or re-entrant)

> **Draw (terrain)**
>
> A draw differs from a valley or an arroyo, in that the ground always
>   slopes downward from a draw in only one direction, and upward in the
>   other three.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draw_(terrain))

[image]

[Picture from armystudyguide.com](http://www.armystudyguide.com/content/army_board_study_guide_topics/land_navigation_map_reading/identify-major-minor-terr.shtml)

Comment: `Draws are similar to valleys on a smaller scale`. I think a `draw` is on a too small a scale for me.

Comment: What scale are you looking for?

Comment: scale of a valley.

Comment: Okay, so 'valley'.

Comment: Yes, see my edit.

Comment: Okay, I think I've found the definitive diagram. I've added it to my 'valley' answer.

Comment: Plus one for *draw* because of that diagram @chaslyfromUK

Answer (score 12):

To be more specific than valley, it's a **combe**.
*Alternative forms are "comb", "coomb" and "coombe"*.

> It defines a short valley or deep hollow, esp in chalk areas, a valley
>   enclosed on all but one side.

[image]

[source](http://www.errorbar.net/rw/Places)

Comment: The question was specifically about valleys in mountains, what makes a word for a valley in downlands an appropriate answer? The placenames incorporating combe are not noticeably in mountainous areas. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combe

Answer (score 11):

*Inlet* is used only for water-filled valleys, so wouldn't be appropriate. **Valley** is correct to describe these formations. Most valleys do not go 'all the way across' a mountain. That would be called a 'pass'

Worldwide there are lots of local words for this type of thing. One of my favourites is **[cwm](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cwm)**, (pronounced "koom") originally a Welsh word but accepted in English, meaning a small bowl-shaped valley. You have already mentioned **coulee**, which is more general and could be applied.

Another English term for something similar, but specifically with steep sides is **[corrie](http://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/higher/geography/physical/lithosphere/revision/6/)** (from the Gaelic *coire*). They can also be referred to as '**bowls**'.

(Incidentally, the definition of *cwm* is evidence of the use of *valley* for a formation that doesn't go all the way across a mountain.)

Comment: Cwm in Welsh; corrie in Irish & Scots Gaelic. Both words have passed into English.

Comment: @TRiG Or rather, _corrie_ in English; _coire_ (meaning literally ‘cauldron’) in Irish and Scottish Gaelic.

Comment: I love using **cwm** in hangman.

Comment: Isn't *coombe* the English spelling of *cwm*?

Answer (score 3):

[Notches](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/notch) or [Saddles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_(landform)).

As you can see on Bald Mountain:

[image: Bald Mountain]

A series of notches can create a saddle.

Comment: A saddle crosses the mountain, that's not what I want. But searching for `notch` I came across (besides a million pictures of the Minecraft dude) the second picture on [this page](https://rockpaperglacier.wordpress.com/road-trip/maine/) which could be what I want, thanks!

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](http://merriam-webster.com/dictionary/notch) defines notch as "a narrow passage between mountains", which isn't quite what you want. Confirmed by the OED, which adds *Chiefly N. Amer.*

Comment: A saddle *by definition* crosses a mountain.

Comment: A saddle is a (flat) point where there are 2 ways up (in this case Reids Peak and Balds Mountain) and 2 ways down. That's not what OP wants. The term "saddle" is also frequently used in maths to describe points on a surface of this type.

Answer (score 2):

**gulch**

> : a small, narrow valley with steep sides
>   [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gulch)

**cove**

> : a deep recess or small valley in the side of a mountain
>   [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cove)

Comment: Yes, and both of these this support the idea that the general term is simply 'valley'.

Answer (score 2):

I would call such a feature simply a **valley**.  In contrast, a passage going *through* the mountains, across a saddle point between two or more peaks, is what I'd call a **pass**.

Note that even valleys formed by rivers or glaciers — which, by their nature, inevitably slope in one direction, away from the mountains — can be quite long, and surrounded by multiple distinct peaks and saddles.  Thus, it's quite possible for there to be several relatively low and easily passable ways in and out of a valley — even if, typically, there's only one way out of a valley that doesn't require you to go uphill *at all*.  If I wished to emphasize that a particular valley was completely surrounded by mountains on all sides but one, with just a single easy way in and out, I might describe it as **enclosed**, or as a **cul-de-sac**, or indeed simply as "surrounded by mountains on all sides but one".

(And no, whether the valley is "[U-shaped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U-shaped_valley)" or "V-shaped" has nothing to do with it.  Those terms just describe the *cross section* of the valley, glacial valleys being typically U-shaped, while river valleys are often V-shaped.)

Answer (score 2):

In the southeast U.S. these are called "hollers", which I always thought was a heavily accented pronunciation of "hollows". Or maybe it's because you can shout across one holler, but not from one into another.

An example of usage might be, "I think Jim keeps his still up the holler." Or if you are hiking with a bunch of kids that keep asking how far it is until camp, the stock answer might be "just around the next holler" (of course, this never comes true).

Answer (score 1):

Dale is roughly synonymous to valley, but has a softer connotation I think. See [Wiktionary.org](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/dale):

> dale ‎(plural dales)
>   1. (Britain) a valley in an otherwise hilly area.
>   "Through wood and dale the sacred river ran," - Kubla Khan by Samuel Taylor Coleridge

Comment: The diagram in the question is clearly of sharper depth than a dale

Comment: There are some "dales" in the UK Peak District with sheer hundred-foot-high rock cliffs on either side. A picture at http://www.zen68262.zen.co.uk/peakwalks-8.html.

Answer (score 0):

How about **canyon**?  And, if it goes nowhere, **box canyon**.

Comment: Canyons go between two 'cliffs' and isn't really describing what he has shown on his question.

Comment: Yes, what @Ruut said, however I think the image I linked to in my edit could be rather misleading. I'll edit again.

Answer (score 0):

Colloquially these are often called crags or clefts.

Comment: please add some citations.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of this is very colloquial and the differences between them if any, are very location specific.  In the northwestern U.S., the word I most often heard was:

> **Gorge**: (1) a narrow cleft with steep, rocky walls, especially one through which a stream runs. (2) a small canyon. ([Source](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/gorge))

Synonyms: ravine, canyon, gully, pass, defile, couloir, deep narrow valley; chasm, abyss, gulf;
dialectchine, bunny;
clough, gill, thrutch;
cleuch, heugh;
gulch, coulee, flume;
arroyo, barranca, quebrada;
nullah, khud;
sloot, kloof, donga;
rare [khor](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/khor)

I suspect most of the problem is that there are a bazillion borrowed words that refer to that small space between two ridges that, themselves, lead to the peak of a single mountain.  I was most entertained by the rare synonym "khor," which apparently originated in the Sudan (not usually the place to inspire images of tall mountains) as a "dry watercourse or ravine."

In my locale, a "valley" is something wide and often (usually) the lowest region between two mountain ranges, not simply between the spurs of the same mountain or the pass between two mountains of the same range.  However, I wouldn't doubt it's used all the time to refer to any or all separations between two ridges (mountains or not).

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the mountains (and location), the inlets could be considered fjords.

Comment: Aren't fjords filled with water?

Comment: fjords on [Google Images](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=fjords&biw=1366&bih=638&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwj4iNCtzYfRAhWEJMAKHdB0An4Q_AUIBigB)

Answer (score -1):

Another word that could work (depending on the imagery you wish to evoke) is *slope*. In a general sense, that could describe any of the sides of the mountain.