# Word for crossing the bottom of a valley

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, geography

To refer to the highest point on a hill, one might use the word "crest":

> He walked up to the crest of the hill, and surveyed his surroundings.

On the other hand, one might also use "crest" as a verb to describe the action of crossing over the top of that hill:

> She looked around as she crested the hill.

I feel as if there should be an equivalent noun/verb pairing to refer specifically to the action of crossing through the bottom of a valley, but I have been unable to find any reference to such a word. Does one even exist?

Examples of base nouns I've considered:

- Valley
- Trough
- Depression
- Saddle
- Channel
- Draw
- Dale
- Dell
- Vale
- Glen

Comment: [Word for inlets of a mountain?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/281856/word-for-inlets-of-a-mountain) and other terms, with diagrams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not be perfect, but it's at least plausible. How about **traverse**?

From your question:

> He walked down to the **traverse** of the valley. [analogous to "the crest of the hill"]

From Dictionary.com:

> [traverse, noun](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/traverse): a place where
>   one may traverse or cross; crossing.

From your question:

> He traversed the valley, and surveyed his surroundings.

From Dictionary.com:

> [traverse, verb](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/traverse): to pass or move
>   over, along, or through.

Acknowledgement: @Mazura mentioned *traverse* in his/her comment on the OP's question.

Comment: @barbecue I know. I found it amazing that there was a one-word solution. Who knew?

Answer (score 4):

This is perhaps a bit fanciful, but one might conceivably say that "she looked around as she **plumbed** the valley".

This sense of the word "plumb" is defined by [oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/plumb) as

> explore or experience fully or to extremes

Comment: However it doesn't really work as the noun for the lowest part of the valley.

Answer (score 3):

From the McGraw-Hill [*Dictionary of Earth Science*](http://yunus.hacettepe.edu.tr/~kdirik/Dictionary_of_Earth_Science.pdf):

> ***valley floor*** The broad flat bottom of a valley. Also known as *valley bottom*; *valley plain*. [*Italics* mine]

So you have a choice of nouns. As a verb, *plain* won't do, and *floor* as a verb means either to furnish with a floor or knock to the floor, literally or figuratively. The *OED* finds "to reach bottom" for a meaning of *bottom*:

> He **bottomed** with his feet and stood upright [in the pond]

But this is likely to clash with the usage *bottom out*, which is reserved for more dynamic things like the movement of stock prices. Perhaps

> She looked around as she descended to the **valley bottom**.

Comment: Crest is to hill, as floor is to valley.

Answer (score 2):

One can **dip** into a **dip**; from [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dip):

> VERB 3. Sink, drop, or slope downwards
>
> ---
>
> NOUN 3. A brief downward slope followed by an upward one.

I don't know if a *dip* is deep enough for you to count as a valley, though.

**Bottom** also comes quite close; from [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bottom):

> *noun*
>   4 a :  the lowest part or place
>
> ---
>
> *intransitive verb*
>   2 :  to reach the bottom
>   3 :  to reach a point where a decline is
>   halted or reversed —usually used with *out*

So you could perhaps say

> He walked down to the **bottom** of the valley, and surveyed his
>   surroundings.

And also

> She looked around as she **bottomed (out)** in the valley.

I say it comes *close* (but maybe no cigar) because in practice the verb most often seems to be used either figuratively or in the context of bodies of water, rather than for literal, non-flooded valleys.

Answer (score 1):

My path *bottomed out* or *flattened out*.  My path *achieved its lowest point*.

That's the closest I can get to what you're imagining.

Answer (score 1):

[THALWEG](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Thalweg):

> A line following the lowest part of a valley, whether under water or not.

(Paraphrased from American Heritage)

Although not a verb itself, one could "cross the thalweg" of a valley.

Comment: Where does that word come from?

Comment: That I had to look up.  Miriam and Wiki have it as 19th century German origin.

Answer (score 0):

***drew to the draws***

(an idiom I just made up; apt to just confuse anyone who isn't a [geography nerd](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/281856/word-for-inlets-of-a-mountain)... even then so)

*Drew* as in 'come upon' and the geography term, *draw*. Traveling between two opposite draws is most likely the furthest distance you can traverse a valley without leaving it.

*We drew to the draws and came up empty; the horse thief must have headed for the hills.*

Comment: I love this example! It does indeed draw out the phrase's poetic potential.

Too bad this is probably too obscure for my application, but you're still getting an upvote for this one!

Comment: Sounds like something from *Deadwood* to me ;)

Comment: An idiom has to be reasonably well known. You've created a non-standard expression.